# Using Smallest width in Android for layout design

Tags: android, layout, width, screen-size, qualifiers

I am developing an App and want my UI to fit as much screens as possible. I have read the Android docs about designing for different screens. Though I have a question which is: There are some phones which are 5.0 inches and some 5.5 inches, please how do I use the sw- qualifier so that 5.0 and 5.5 design can be different. Or can I get a suggestion of the most commonly used sw- qualifiers, like how we had the small, normal and large, I have seen the ones given in the docs:

320dp: a typical phone screen.

480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).

600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).

720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

So which of these should I use for a 5.5 inch screen? 
Is there any single dp size that all the 5.5 inch screen can adjust to, so that if I am developing for 5.5 inch I just use it?

Comment: `320dp: a typical phone screen.` and `720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).` are too generalized. My current phone (4.7" wide) has a 1280x720 resolution with a normalized density of 320 dpi (xhdpi). I encourage you to read [Supporting multiple screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) from the official docs.

Comment: Yes I get what you are saying, and I have read all the docs that need to be read ....actually :/,.. what i am trying to get is, assuming I am to develop for your phone, does that mean I will design for your phone (4.7), design for 5.0,5.5,6.0... for all of them also taking into consideration that not all 5.0 inch phones are equal. That the question is do I need to design for all of them, if so the I can go in with it. Why i asked this is before when it was just small, normal, and large it was faster.

Answer (score 0):

ild just use what's in the docs just for now, what is in the docs is below:

For other cases in which you want to further customize your UI to differentiate between sizes such as 7” and 10” tablets, you can define additional smallest width layouts:

res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)